# How do I find out what modules a component or service is dependent on?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to make my modules lazy loaded, and to do so I must be sure that no component or service from one module is dependent on another module's components or services.
Is there any way to build a graph or another kind of diagram to check dependencies between components and services?

For now I only think about writing a piece of code that would parse all the components, modules and services, and then will check their dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `ngd` to generate a dependency graph report.

https://github.com/compodoc/ngd

Answer (score 3):

You can use Angular Augury, see docs here:
https://augury.rangle.io/pages/guides/io-demo.html

And these are some of its features (Dependency graph and lazy loaded modules)

[image]

And this is the list of your modules and all their declaration/providers/imports..etc

[image]

Comment: This works good, but I think it only reports about the current state of the app. It's not a graph of how the app is built. So the graph changes depending on up what components are currently on the page. I might be wrong about that. I haven't use it in a while.

Comment: Nice, hints guys, thanks!

I would like to just add a note about Augury deprecation - https://github.com/rangle/augury#angular-devtools.
It was replaced by Angular DevTools - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angular-devtools/ienfalfjdbdpebioblfackkekamfmbnh?hl=pt-br - according the Augury documentation.